# GNOME3/GDM first login fails but second login succeeds

Tags: gnome, login, gnome3, gdm, gdm3

When my system boots up, and I click my username, and enter my password, the login attempt fails. However, when I try the exact same password again, I can successfully log in. What could have caused this? I am using the latest arch Linux on the latest gnome3/gdm.

Comment: does it happen if you try to login over SSH or via the console?

Comment: no it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized that for some reason, the first key I press on my USB keyboard does not get registered.

Answer (score 0):

My Fedora system has had this since version 26 or so (on 31 now). I noticed that Gnome logins don't start working until the text console login prompts on PTY 2..6 become available. Likely, the GDM login screen just pops up too early.

Comment: Please explain how your answer can deal with it

Comment: You can check if any of the text consoles are up before attempting a graphical login (by pressing Alt-Ctrl-F2, for example, and then back to Alt-Ctrl-F1)